# Auto adjust view position when personal hotspot on and off

Tags: ios, autolayout

When personal hotspot gets turned on, the status bar height change from 20 to 40 points, the `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]` returned `CGRect` would change from ((0, 20), (screenWidth, screenHeight - 20)) to ((0, 40), (screenWidth, screenHeight - 40)).

When personal hotspot gets turned off, the status bar height change from 40 to 20 points, the `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]` returned `CGRect` would change from ((0, 40), (screenWidth, screenHeight - 40)) to ((0, 20), (screenWidth, screenHeight - 20)).

The problem is I initialized my view using the applicationFrame CGRect in the init method, but the Personal Hotspot can be turned on and off at any moment. The view needs to be adjusting its frame in real-time, which I guess it should be something like auto layout or autoresizing, but don't know exactly how to do it?

And, in particular, for iOS 5 devices, auto layout is not available, how can we do it?

Comment: Is this problem now resolved with the auto layout in iOS 9?